# What is the English equivalent of the French word "consigne" in English (in the classroom context)?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, translation, french

What is the English equivalent of the French word "consigne"? I am referring here to the classroom context, so in phrases such as "consigne de l'exercice". See also the picture at the bottom of the post.

Additionally, can we use "rule", "guidelines"?

Using Linguee to check ["consigne"](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=consigne), it gives "guidelines", and, as rarer, "instruction".

Using Linguee to check ["consigne de l'exercice"](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=consigne%20de%20l%27exercice), it gives only one result (the others are not related to the school system), and interestingly, it does not translate the word "instruction".

> "donne les consignes de chaque exercice" --> "Each exercise is
> explained"

A machine translation tool gives ["instruction of the exercise"](https://translate.yandex.com/dictionary/fr-en/la%20consigne%20de%20l%27exercice).

In this picture of an exercise, what we would call a "consigne" in French is squared in red with a red arrow pointed to it. The original image before this personal modification comes from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.liveworksheets.com%2Fuz870280qq&psig=AOvVaw2_fHG4mHceXwjSqDQoZjOU&ust=1667822995588000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA4QjhxqFwoTCLjR5vvCmfsCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI)
[image: Picture of an exercise]

Comment: I speak French, though I haven't used it much for years and I'm not familiar with the classroom context. If it refers to explaining how to do an exercise, I can't think of anything better than _explanation_ or _guidelines_.

Comment: It would appear that "Each exercise is explained" makes *consigne* mean *explanation.* I'm not sure English has the same construction at all: we would say something like "How to do the exercise."

Comment: I would call the things in your example *directions*, but I suspect that there is no one word which would translate all French educational uses of *consigne*.

Comment: Thank you Kate Bunting, Andrew Leach and Peter Shor. I added a picture to be clearer. So you would call "2. Answer the questions using "Getting something done". Choose from the box" (in the picture at the bottom of the post") an "explanation"?

Comment: The feel of the word is close to the English word *charge*, in the sense of assignment, though charge isn't usually used that way.

Comment: There are related terms like *rubric* which according to M-W is a [guideline for grading academic papers](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rubric) but I'm sure I've seen used more loosely. *Instructions* or *guidance* seem similar, but I'd reserve *guidance* for material that isn't part of the formal requirements but is providing help. That leaves *instructions* which seems fine, as the example isn't an explanation, additional guidance, or marking instructions - it's the main text telling the student what they need to do.

Comment: Note that the machine translation tool gave a bad translation; it should be *instructions **for** the exercise*. I guess prepositions are just as hard for computers as they are for people.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you very much. I indeed think it is "instruction", ok for your explanation about "guidance". What about "guidelines" or "rules"? Peter Shor: In French, conceptually, an exercise *has* a "consigne" (a "consigne" is really a substantial part of the exercise), so we say "the instruction ***of*** the exercise". If find it strange not to be able to say  "the instruction ***of*** the exercise"

Comment: @starckman: In this case *instructions* are used with the preposition *for*, not *of*. You say *the instruction **of** the child* (*l'enseignement de l'enfant*) but *the instructions **for** assembly* (*les instructions de montage*).

Comment: The word *guidelines* would be a much looser term ... it sounds to me more like a suggested way for doing the exercise rather than a required one. And *rules* wouldn't generally be used here, even though the meaning is appropriate.

Comment: Dear @PeterShor, I am not fully aware of the habits in this forum, but if all your comments were gathered in one post, I would like to accept this answer. (So basically, the equivalent term is "instructions")

Comment: If somebody else doesn't post a good answer first, I'lll do it when I have time.

Comment: Linguee is not a good place to check these things. consignes here means instructions. Bear in mind that the word is used in many places that are not a classroom. And no, we don't say of the exercise. There are tons of examples were de in French is not of in English. In other contexts, it can be rules or guidelines or orders (military and cops).

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary does have an entry for this word

**Consigne** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consigne))

Under the French heading

1. **orders, instructions**
2. bottle deposit
3. baggage locker, luggage locker
   (in an airport, railway station, etc.)

The pertinent one to your query is the first definition.

Comment: In the given context, "instruction" / "instructions" would be more appropriate than "orders".

Comment: Are "rules" and "guidelines" possible in that context?

Comment: If you look in [Wiktionnaire français](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/consigne), it looks like *consigne* is often used in military contexts, for which *orders, instructions* is a reasonable translation.

Comment: @PeterShor Sure, I feel judicial police, riot control agents use it as well. "consigne" is very pervasive in the school context (textbooks), I don't understand why this meaning is not registered in the Wiktionary

Comment: @starckman What about [here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/consigne) or [here](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/consigne/18392)?

Comment: Here: *Instruction formelle donnée à quelqu'un, qui est chargé de l'exécuter* (From the Larousse) @tchrist

Comment: Note that *formelle* means here "clearly expressed, unequivocal".

Comment: @tchrist Thank you. The cnrtl definition doesn't mention the textbook related meaning, and the Larousse definition "Instruction formelle donnée à quelqu'un, qui est chargé de l'exécuter" is quite broad, and I think quite different from the textbook related meaning (the textbook's user is not obliged to do the exercise!)

Comment: For the military, consignes are orders. Also, for cops. = Instruction formelle donnée à quelqu'un, qui est chargé de l'exécuter" In the military, if you are given an order, you are supposed to execute it, perform the task.

Comment: @starckman *Consigne* has no specific textbook meaning in French. While overlapping concepts, a *consigne* is always softer than an *ordre*. A *consigne* describes what needs to be done in a specific situation, it's more a rule. A soldier who doesn't respect the *consigne* will have to provide (convincing) explanations, a soldier who doesn't respect an *order* is in big trouble. In a textbook, not respecting the *consigne* is harmless but also pointless.

Comment: An engaging discussion. Judging from all the comments, can it be said that 'consigne' means 'formal instruction'?

Comment: @jlliagre I think you are correct, the second part of my response to tchrist was flawed

Answer (score 0):

Some English speakers may use the word ***prompt*** for this purpose. It is a word that has its origin in the educational jargon, but has recently been percolating into everyday usage (I suspect because teachers get habituated to using the word in the course of their own education, and then let it slip when communicating with their students).

I post this answer only hesitantly because I don't wish to encourage further expansion of the use of this word.

Comment: I'd upvote this answer, except I agree with you about not encouraging this use of the word.